# define two different login process in one app

Tags: php, authentication, yii, identity

I have a problem with the login process in my yii app. I have two different kind of users including admin users that manage the site and customers. I'm using `CwebUser` and `UserIdentitiy` to manage login of these two groups.  But my problem is that when a customer login in the site he can access to admin pages too.  What I want to do is to say the application to create two different identity session for them. I don't want to use something like access control rules.  Is there any way to create different sessions for them in Yii style?

Comment: I don't really think that is good practice...
Role Based Access Control really seems like the right thing to do... It is something plenty of extensions already do and helps keep your webapp mantainable..

Comment: I'm agree with you but in my case I have two different tables... I don't know how can I use RBAC on two different tables...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use a complex RBAC setup like suggested in one of the comments, you can achieve this if you configure 2 user components with different `stateKeyPrefix`:

```
'user' => array(              // Webuser for the frontend
    'class'             => 'CWebUser',
    'loginUrl'          => array('site/login'),
    'stateKeyPrefix'    => 'frontend_',
),
'adminUser' => array(         // Webuser for the admin area (admin)
    'class'             => 'CWebUser',
    'loginUrl'          => array('/admin/site/login'),
    'stateKeyPrefix'    => 'admin_',
),
```

So now you have 2 independent user components: `user` and `adminUser`. You have to create another `AdminLoginForm` and `AdminUserIdentity` which you use in `/admin/site/login` to do the authentication. This should be straightforward.

Though you still have the problem, that you can't easily define `accessRules` in your admin module, because it would use the `user` component to perform the authorization checks whereas you want it to use the `adminUser` component. To solve this, you can alter the component configuration in your `AdminModule` like this:

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {
        if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller,$action))
        {
            // Make 'adminUser' the main user in this module.
            // Frontend user is available as 'Yii::app()->frontendUser'.
            Yii::app()->setComponent('frontendUser', Yii::app()->user);
            Yii::app()->setComponent('user', Yii::app()->adminUser);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can login into 2 different sections of your site, both using a different user base for authentication.

Comment: @Michael Härtl Exactly what I want...thank you...  But little bit of problem. When I logout from frontend it also logout from back end. How to solve that problem ?

Comment: @SKG Make sure you call `logout(false)` to not destroy *all* session information (see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#logout-detail)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. If you have two login pages, you can easily use two `CUserIdentity` subclasses. Then, your authentication process can be very different.

If your login page needs to be the same for both sets of users, it will get a bit more involved. But it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved my problem is something like @michael solution but with some difference. I've defined two different user component in my config file : `user` and `customer` :

```
 'user' => array(
            'loginUrl' => '/admin/default/login',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'customer' => array(
            'class' => 'NWebUser',
            'loginUrl' => '/customer/signIn',
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
```

For customers I've defied an extended class from `CWebUser` named `NWebUser`. It's just an empty class. besides them I've defined another class which extend `UserIdentity` Calls `CustomerIdentity` in wich I've defined my customer authenticate method:

```
class CustomerIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    private $_id;

    public function authenticate() {
        $record = Customer::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => $this->username));
        if ($record === null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } else if ($record->password !== Customer::hashPassword($this->password)) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        } else {
            $this->_id = $record->id;
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}
```

Now in my login method I just use this CustomerIdentity class :

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->_identity === null) {
            $this->_identity = new CustomerIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
        if ($this->_identity->errorCode === CustomerIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
            $duration = $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0; // 30 days
            Yii::app()->customer->login($this->_identity, $duration);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: You don't set a `stateKeyPrefix` so i very much assume that if you login as `customer` you're also logged in as `user`.